# What should be the criteria for Scaling Up.Down Autoscaling group using min_instances,max_instances and desired capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, autoscaling, amazon-ec2, boto3

I wanted to Scale Up/Down AutoScaleGroup.But it is difficult to decide the best practices for choosing the **desiredCapacity** based on the min_instances,max_instances and desired capacity.
What are the edge cases to handle and best practices required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desiredCapacity is based on the following factor: (Expected load)/(% of expected load that a single instance can handle)

desiredCapacity is the number of instances that AutoScalingGroup will launch at first. Also, the min/max instances are just a limit to min and max number of instances at a time in your ASG.

Now, if the actual load fluctuates than the "Expected load", that's when you would need to either scale up or down your number of instances.

The actual load fluctuations can be determined by a number of factors. For e.g. if the %CPU usage of your current instances increases to 80% (say), then AutoScalingGroup needs to launch 4 (say) more instances. You can use other metrics as well to determine the load like memory, latency (custom metrics) etc.
To achieve the above, you would need some other resources like CloudWatch to get the metrics and ScalingPolicy to scale up or down.

You can get a hang of it from the sample templates mentioned at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-services-us-west-2.html#d0e66913